# Solving a MaxValue differential equation numerically

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I need to numerically solve the differential equation $$\partial_x u(x) = \sup_{\alpha \in (0,1)} \int_\mathbb{R} b(\alpha,z)u(z)dz + \max\{0, u(x) - C\},$$
where $C$ is a constant and $b$ is a certain continuous function in Mathematica and solve it numerically.

I know how to write partial derivatives using the Mathematica software, but I'm not sure about how to enter the $\sup$ term ([`MaxValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxValue.html)) and rearrange the equation so that `NDSolve` can work.

Comment: It's called `MaxValue` in Mathematica. See [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Supremum.html).

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thank you. Could you please write up an answer showing me a sample working code (taking $b(\alpha,z) = \frac{1}{|z|^\alpha}$ and $C = 250$)?

Comment: What is `u` a function of in `u - C`? It's gotta be `x`, right?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, $u$ is the unknown and a function of $x$ (I edited the question for clarity).

Comment: I would suggest an [MWE](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-do-we-mean-by-a-self-contained-minimal-working-example) would help, but after a little thought, I don't think `NDSolve` can do this.  (You need to know `u`, the unknown, to compute the integral with `NIntegrate`.) I can imagine manually programming a finite-element type approach [a la Chebfun](http://www.chebfun.org/examples/integro/WikiIntegroDiff.html) -- do you know of an algorithm for such a problem as this?